# Custom Pop up message when a SharePoint form loads

Tags: jquery, custom-form, popup

I have a custom SharePoint 2013 form that I'm working on that I need to create a popup warning for on the page load. This pop up needs to be able to link to other sections in the site. I've checked around, I don't think an alert will give me what I need because I need to add links. I have not been able to find a solution online that does what I need it to do.

Comment: What I'd try is to open the Modal Dialog from SP with JavaScript.
Documentation here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff410058(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: That does look like it would work, but for some reason when I throw it in my code, it just breaks it. I just paste it inbetween the scripts tag and updated the url and its kaput.

Answer (score 0):

For this issue, I believe you could make use of two different methods (depending on your specific requirement):

- Make use of the [SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff410058%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) option. You can link to an existing URL or simply add your required HTML tags (e.g. a-tags for URL's) within the "html" parameter of this method.
- Make use of simple HTML/CSS/JS to display the modal on page load (example [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/txnxaxex/3/)):

**HTML**

```
<p>This is the content of the page</p>
<div id="modal" class="modal">
  <div class="warning">
    <div>
      <span class="exit">&times;</span>
      <a href="https://www.google.com">Google</a>
    </div>
    <a href="https://www.google.com/random">Some SharePoint URL</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.modal {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding-top: 20px;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.warning {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
}

.exit {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
var modal = document.getElementById('modal');
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("exit")[0];

span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

Hope this works for you! Please let me know what you ended up using.

Kind Regards,

Robin